# A quick 4 line riddle

Tags: riddle

> I rank above all but nobody listens to me
>   I'm not very useful but you would be lost without me
>   People check up on me otherwise I might go stale
>   My home is lost without my birds

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> The Chess King

I rank above all but nobody listens to me

> Most important piece, but the player is in command

I'm not very useful but you would be lost without me

> Doesn't move far or threaten much, but the game is lost if he is.

People check up on me otherwise I might go stale

> Game ends in checkmate or stalemate

My home is lost without my birds

> Can't Castle (home) if you don't have an available Rook (bird)

Comment: Correct on all clues, well done